# Is it possible to set background color in xml using CDATA?

Tags: android, string, android-xml, cdata

I'm setting the font color using the following code

```
<string name="my_name">
 <![CDATA[
   <font color="#FF0000">
   Test  
   </font>
 ]]>
</string>
```

I couldn't find any where how to set background color of the String using similar method.

Answer (score 0):

hi i hope this helps you 
*if you want an Xml value  of colors*

```
<color name= "myColor" > #FF0000 </color>
```

*plus you can give almost any background color to an Xml view*

```
android:background="#FF0000"
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not the problem I'm facing.

Comment: sorry didn't reed the hole question :0/